# get iis server address when inserting data in sql sever 2005

Tags: sql-server, iis

When a user on my site registers and his data is  inserted into a table on sql server 2005 I need to know from which iis server the user arrived - not the users ip address. (there are 2 different server addresses under a server in iis from which the data could have been received). I then need to get the address and insert it into another table.
How can I receive this address?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The Host_Name() function does not return the ip address. I'm not clear on how to receive this connection data.

Comment: Ah!  You need to be more clear - I thought when you said you didn't want the users IP address, you wanted "which IIS server", I thought you meant the NAME.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! I will suggest it and get back to you about the solution. Thanks! Is there no way of getting into the log of a certain connection to the database and getting the iis ip address directly?

Comment: have edited my answer to show some code.

Comment: I'm getting confused. I need to get the ip address of the iis servers. The website connects to  different iis servers and they need to know which iis server was used every time a user registers on the web site. host_name() will give the workstation name. @@servername seems to give the name of the sql server , not the iis server. How do I get the iis server name/ip address?  I need to be clear on what the difference is between the iis server name and the workstation name.Thanks again!

Comment: in your case host_name() is the name of the IIS server.  Forget @@servername - you're right that is the SQL server name.

Comment: Your ASP.NET code will have to find this information. And keep in mind that a single server may have multiple IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HOST_NAME() function

EDIT: OP clarified that he wants IIS server IP address.

Can you resolve the name to an IP using a lookup table? Presumably the IIS servers don't change that dynamically?

EDIT: some code

If you've got xp_cmdshell enabled you could try something along the lines of

```
declare @hostip varchar(50)
declare @hostname varchar(50)
declare @cmd varchar(8000) 

set @hostname = HOST_NAME()

set @cmd = 'ping -n 1 ' + @hostname

create table #temp (pingoutput varchar(max)) 

insert into #temp exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd 
select @hostip = substring(pingoutput,  charindex('[',pingoutput)+1, charindex(']',pingoutput)-charindex('[',pingoutput)-1) 
from #temp
where left(pingoutput,7) = 'Pinging' 

select @hostip 

drop table #temp
```

replace the @hostname with whatever you have to find the IP of a given name, or use as-is to get the host ip

---

EDIT: some further thoughts

The 'ping' method to get the IP address of HOST_NAME() may not work if your web servers are in a DMZ

If it is IIS web logs that you are trying to import, are you aware of the [s-ip] field you can add to the W3C extended log format.  This would add the web server ip to the log entries.